# $_GET to create product page

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to create a product page based on the passed in ID from the URL, I get this error:

> Fatal error: Cannot use object of type Product as array in E:\xampp\htdocs\DiamondCommerce\product.php on line 4

```
<?php
//URL would be diamond.dev/product?{id}
require_once 'dbconfig.php';
$product_id = $_GET[$product['product_id']]; 
$currentProduct = $DB_con->prepare("SELECT * FROM products where product_id = :this_product_id LIMIT 1");
$product_id->bindParam(":this_product_id"   , $product_id);   
$currentProduct->execute();
$currentProductInfo = $currentProduct->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
//if isset for button
?>
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title><?php $currentProduct['product_name']?></title>
</head>
<body>
<?php 
foreach($currentProductInfo as $currentProduct) 
{
echo '<p>',$currentProduct['product_name'],'</p>';  
echo '<p>',$currentProduct['product_description'],'</p>';   
echo '<p>',$currentProduct['product_price'],'</p>'; 
echo '<p>',$currentProduct['product_image'],'</p>';
echo '<a href="#" class="btn btn-primary" name="addToBasket">Add to Basket</a>';
}
?>
</body>
</html>
```

The URL looks fine (example: http://diamond.dev/product.php?id=5), which is what I want, but I don't know what is causing this error. Greatly appreciate any help.

Comment: `?id` and you're using `$_GET[$product['product_id']]` - where is `$_GET['id']`? and how is `$product` being populated?

Comment: I noticed that immediately after I posted, now this is the issue: Fatal error: Call to a member function bindParam() on string in E:\xampp\htdocs\DiamondCommerce\product.php on line 6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error comes from this line:

```
<title><?php $currentProduct['product_name']?></title>
```

Which is fair enough because $currentProduct is defined as

```
$currentProduct = $DB_con->prepare("SELECT * FROM products where product_id = :this_product_id LIMIT 1");
```

In other words $currentProduct is a prepared statement and not an array. You probably meant to use `$currentProductInfo` in your title.